# To find the row that hosts a specific value in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
A      B   C    D
SNP_1 100 130 0.03
SNP_2 130 160 0.33
SNP_3 160 190 0.32
```

and would like to find the row that flanks the value of 120 (based on column B and C)

Which is
row 1 `SNP_1 100 130 0.03`

Thanks for your suggestions
M

I tried using the which function -- but not sure if I am doing it the correct way

```
df$E <- NA
df$E[which(df$B>=120 & df$C <=120)] <- "YES"
```

Comment: That code looks appropriate>

Comment: The code as written would return FALSE for all rows as no colC values are less than or equal to 120.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be useful:

```
dt[dt$B <= 120 & dt$C >= 120,]
      A   B   C    D
1 SNP_1 100 130 0.03
```